Adding labels from custom fields during item creation in github projects board view
It is possible to create new items in each pane of a board view.
After clicking in + Add item a new text window appears in the bottom.
We can link to a project by typing # and selecting the project from the list.
Is there a shortcut to automatically add project's custom fields during item creation from text?
Right now I have to create the item, then select the item, then add the custom field manually on the side pane. I wish there were a faster approach.
Thank you in advance.
